# Adicionar diferentes escalas no matplotlib

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

Gostaria de uma ajuda para configurar a escala do eixo Y. Ao tentar plotar um gráfico de barras com valores baixos e altos, os menores acabam não aparecendo na escala. Tentei algumas opções, mas não fica como gostaria. Abaixo estão os gráficos, o plotado, e uma ilustração de como gostaria:[image: plotado]

[image: ilustrado]

E o código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["T1","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","T9"]
y = [4,6,4,7,40,60,80,700,800]

#plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.bar(x, y, color='red')
plt.title('Tratamentos Herbicidas')
plt.xlabel('Tratamentos')
plt.ylabel('Num')
#plt.autoscale(axis="y")
#plt.yscale('log',basey=2)
#plt.yticks(range(0,max(y),50))
#plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Desde já, obrigado por qualquer ajuda!!

Comment: você não acha que um eixo duplo não seria suficiente para resolver seu problema?

Comment: Bom dia Lucas, obrigado pela resposta. Porém não entendi muito bem como ficaria isso no gráfico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um problema de visualização de dados. Sua solução proposta seria "quebrar" o eixo Y em diferentes alturas, porém na minha opinião, isso simplesmente faz com que você perca informação - qual o sentido de usar altura de barras pra indicar valores, se as alturas não têm correspondência proporcional aos valores?

Há formas mais ou menos elegantes de quebrar os eixos - veja [esse exemplo do matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html). Formar essa figura não é algo trivial, pois envolve plotar diversos `Axes` (gráficos) na figura, cada uma correspondendo a uma parte do eixo quebrado.

No seu caso, há uma solução mais simples: utilizar escala logarítmica no eixo Y. As barras continuam proporcionais aos valores, mas devido às propriedades de logaritmos, fica mais fácil de visualizar os dados de valor baixo. Para isso, basta adicionar a linha

```
plt.yscale('log')
```

Diretamente antes de chamar `plt.show()`.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia jfaccioni, muito obrigado, ajudou demais, realmente ficou muito melhor para leitura.